# How to upload files and display them as list item?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

So I have a webpage that has Downloadable books and I just added an option to upload books to my server but I want so when they upload the file it to display on the main page. Heres my code.

main page where I want my uploaded files to display

```
<html>    
        <head> 

            <title>Book Store</title>  
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo2.ico" />
             <link href = "style1.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />  
        </head>    
        <body> 

        <style>

    </style>

    </div>
        <h1>Book Store</h1>
         <input type="text" id="booksearch" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search for books.."size="40">
    <ul id="myUL">
      <li><a href="">A</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="alice.epub">Alice and Wonderland</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="">B</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="Bible kjv pdf.html">Bible King James Version</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="">H</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="hunted down.epub">Hunted Down by Charles Dickens</a></li><br> 
      <li><a href="">P</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="Pilgrim progress.html">Pilgrim Progress</a></li>
      <li><a href="Pride and Prejudice.epub">Pride and Prejudice epub</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="">S</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="Sherlock Holmes complete book.epub">Sherlock Holmes complete book epub</a></li>
      <li><a href="cano.pdf">Sherlock Holmes complete book pdf</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="">T</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="Holmes.pdf" download>The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes pdf</a><br></li>
      <li><a href="fatherbrown1.epub">The Innocence of Father Brown book ep 1 epub</a></li>
      <li><a href="fatherbrown2.epub">The Wisdom of Father Brown book ep 2 epub</a></li>
      <li><a href="fatherbrown3.epub">The Incredulity Of Father Brown book ep 3 epub</a></li>
      <li><a href="fatherbrown4.epub">The Scandal Of Father Brown ep 4 epub</a></li>
      <li><a href="fatherbrown5.epub">The Secret Of Father Brown ep 5 epub</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="">N</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="nontredam.epub">Nontre Dam history</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="">R</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="romeo.epub">Romeo and Juliet</a></li>
    </ul>   
    <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.faultexception.reader">Get free epub reader for android</a><br>
    <script>
    function search() {
      // Declare variables
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById('booksearch');
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
      li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

      // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
    </script>





           <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="600">    





    <button onclick="JavaScript:alert('You will love this book!')">
    <img src="http://moziru.com/images/book-clipart-cartoon-14.jpg" alt="What We think of this Book" height = "100">
    <br>What We think of this Book</button>
    <br>
    <a href="html.html" atnip construction>Atnip Construction</a><br>
    <a href="archive.html" atnip construction>Upload a Book</a><br>
    <a href="store.html" atnip construction>sign up</a><br>



        </body>    
    </html>
```

upload PHP code named upload.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
        $file = $_FILES['file'];

        $file_name = $file['name'];
        $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
        $file_size = $file['size'];
        $file_error = $file['error'];

        $file_ext = explode(".", $file_name);
        $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

        $allowed = array("epub", "pdf", "mp4"); //The extensions you allow

        if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {
            if ($file_error === 0) {
                if ($file_size <= 2097152) {
                    $file_destination = ''.$file_name; // If ' ', the file will be placed in this directory
                    if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
                        echo $file_destination;
                    } else {
                        echo "An error has been encountered while moving your file!";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Your file is too big!";
                }
            } else {
                echo "An error has been encountered while uploading your file!";
            } 
        } else {
            echo "You can't upload files of this type!";
        }
    }
?>
```

And if it's important I am using 000webhosting. Thanks in advance if any more info is needed please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use a database or a file.
Both of these answers involve having to write the data somewhere and then get it and display it on the webpage.

**Since you want a file solution, the code below will do the trick.**

The HTML for the upload page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" required/> 
            File: <input type="file" name="file" required/> 
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The PHP for the upload page:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_FILES['file']) && isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $file = $_FILES['file'];

        $file_name = $file['name'];
        $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
        $file_size = $file['size'];
        $file_error = $file['error'];

        $file_ext = explode(".", $file_name);
        $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

        $allowed = array("epub", "pdf", "mp4"); //The extensions you allow

        if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {
            if ($file_error === 0) {
                if ($file_size <= 2097152) {    //the maximum filesize
                    $file_destination = ''.$file_name;  // If ' ', the file will be placed in this directory
                    if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
                        echo $file_destination;

                        $fp = fopen('book_list.txt', "a");
                        fwrite($fp, $_POST['name']. "|||" .$file_destination."\n");
                        fclose($fp);

                    } else {
                        echo "An error has been encountered while moving your file!";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Your file is too big!";
                }
            } else {
                echo "An error has been encountered while uploading your file!";
            } 
        } else {
            echo "You can't upload files of this type!";
        }
    }
?>
```

And then something like this in the php script which well display the content:

```
<?php
    $content = file('book_list.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    foreach ($content as $cont) {
        $names = explode("|||", $cont);
        echo "<li><a href='example.com/path_to_upload.php/".$names[1]."'>".$names[0]."</a></li>";   //if upload.php is in the root directory of your website, remove "path_to_upload.php/"
    }
?>
```

You should turn your main page to a `.php` file so you can just include the code inside of the `<ul>` tag.

Comment: I want to use a file but how would you do that?

Comment: If you don't intend to have alot of items in the file there's no problem, but if you want to have alot of items I suggest you use a database.

Comment: I could use a database but I haven't had good luck with them.

Comment: After the upload is complete, take the name of the file and append it into a file, and later on use `file()` to get the file as an array of lines and then echo the content onto the webpage.

Comment: Is there a way to have it automatic and have a link to download off the website?

Comment: Also I would suggest you use the other code in my answer on your last question for the upload script because this one uploads the file but you can't view or access the file afterwords.

Comment: Yes, you can do this automatically with a php script and create a download link.

Comment: I actually can veiw and acces the file with this code in my file manager.

Comment: Strange, it didn't work for me but if you're okay with it then great.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205051/discussion-between-coder-and-leon-kunstek).

Comment: Well I could post it in my answer. But you would also need to get the real title of the book because the file doesn't necessarily have to be named the same as the book.

Comment: could there be input on the HTML file possibly?

Comment: You could put an input on the website where the file is being uploaded.

Comment: how do I get it to display on index.html as a downloadable file

Comment: As I've seen, as soon as I clicked on one of the links, the file started downloading on my phone. You could also make a download script if that doesn't work.

Comment: the links already on there work but I want that when  I upload a book it automatically goes to a downloadable link on main page

Comment: The new book will have a download link. You can add one and then try.

Comment: now it wont allow to upload pdf but it works for epub whats the problem

Comment: you cant upload this file type